# Change the Image Position Using PDFBox 2.0

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have add an QR code image using below code and it works well. Below is the snapshot how it displayed currently:

[image: EXISTING QRCODE IMAGE]

Now, as per other requirement need to change the position of the already added QRcode. As per the request parameters I can get position related parameters. But I have no idea that what I should take to achieve this. Either,

1. By removing existing image first and then add again with new position values or
2. Need to change existing add image logic to achieve it in some other way.

Please guide me on this as I have new to start with PDFBox. Below is the  reference code to add image:

```
    PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(new File(SourceFilePath()));
    int total = pdDocument.getNumberOfPages();
    
    PDPage page = pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0);
    PDRectangle rectangle = getRotatedMediaBox(page);
    
    PDPage pdPage = new PDPage(rectangle);
    PDDocument newDocument = new PDDocument();
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        pdPage = newDocument.importPage(pdDocument.getPage(i));
        PDRectangle pageRect = getRotatedMediaBox(pdPage);
        
        int rotation = pdPage.getRotation();
        
        PDRectangle cropBoxRect =  page.getCropBox();
        
        //Calculate margin between crop box rectangle and page rectangle.
        float[] margins = getCropBoxMargin(pageRect, cropBoxRect, rotation);
        
        if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270) {
            cropBoxRect = new PDRectangle(cropBoxRect.getLowerLeftY(), cropBoxRect.getLowerLeftX(), cropBoxRect.getHeight(),
                    cropBoxRect.getWidth());
        }
        
        
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = getImage();
        PDPageContentStream pageContentStream = new PDPageContentStream(newDocument, pdPage,
                PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true);
        PDImageXObject image = JPEGFactory.createFromImage(newDocument, bufferedImage);
        
        if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270) {
            Matrix matrix = Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(rotation), 0, 0);
            PDRectangle cropBox = pdPage.getCropBox();
            float tx = (cropBox.getLowerLeftX() + cropBox.getUpperRightX()) / 2;
            float ty = (cropBox.getLowerLeftY() + cropBox.getUpperRightY()) / 2;
    
            Rectangle rectang = cropBox.transform(matrix).getBounds();
            float scale = Math.min(cropBox.getWidth() / (float)rectang.getWidth(), cropBox.getHeight() / (float)rectang.getHeight());
    
            pageContentStream.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(tx, ty));
            pageContentStream.transform(matrix);
            pageContentStream.transform(Matrix.getScaleInstance(scale, scale));
            pageContentStream.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(-tx, -ty));
        }
        
                XMPMetadata xmp = XMPMetadata.createXMPMetadata();
                
                DublinCoreSchema dc = xmp.createAndAddDublinCoreSchema();
                dc.setTitle(imgUniqueId);
                
                XmpSerializer serializer = new XmpSerializer();
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                serializer.serialize(xmp, baos, true);
                
                PDMetadata metadata = new PDMetadata(pdDocument);
                metadata.importXMPMetadata(baos.toByteArray());
                image.setMetadata(metadata);
        pageContentStream.drawImage(image, rectLlx, rectLly, qrImageSize, qrImageSize);
        pageContentStream.close();
    }
    newDocument.save(new File(DestinationFilePath(false)));
    
    newDocument.close();
    pdDocument.close();
```

Comment: Is the QR code the only image in the PDF? If not, by which criteria can it be recognized?

Comment: Yes there can be multiple images on the page and I'm differentiating it using image  metadata added while inserting QRCode on the page. Edited question summary to add that  code.

Comment: PDF isn't really good for editing, this is much pain. So make it right the first time, thus "change existing add image logic". Having said that, I don't understand what the question is now.

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr I have changed the image positioning strategy a little by taking reference of an answer given by you in some other thread and that made work to me. Thanks